# Angular - Why the "[selected]" works in a case but not in another?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I was creating a form for editing a user's data, but I came to an impasse when I needed to use two "selects" in the form.

The curiosity here is that a select works correctly and the other does not.

My code in component.ts:

```js
teams = [
    {id: 0, name: Team[Team.Mobile]},
    {id: 1, name: Team[Team.Frontend]},
    {id: 2, name: Team[Team.Backend]}
  ]

  genders = [
    {id: 0, name: Gender[Gender.Male]},
    {id: 1, name: Gender[Gender.Female]},
    {id: 2, name: Gender[Gender.Other]},
  ]

  employeeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: '',
    gender: [2],
    birthDate: '',
    email: '',
    startDate: '',
    cpf: '',
    team:[2]
  });  

  ngOnInit(): void {        

    this.peopleService.getPeopleById(this.list[0].employeeId)
      .subscribe(
        people => {    
          
          this.employee = people;
          
          this.employeeForm.patchValue({
            name: people.name,
            gender: [people.gender],
            birthDate: new Date(people.birthDate),
            email: people.email,
            startDate: new Date(people.startDate),
            cpf: people.cpf,
            team: [people.team]
          });
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  get gender() {
    return this.employeeForm.get('gender').value;
  }

  get team() {
    return this.employeeForm.get('team').value;
  }
```

My HTML template:

```
<form [formGroup]="employeeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">                
       
       ...

       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>            
            <select class="form-control" id="gender" formControlName="gender">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let genderEl of genders">
                    <option [ngValue]="genderEl.id" [selected] = "gender == genderEl.id">{{genderEl.name}}</option>
                </ng-container>        
            </select>
        </div>                   

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="team">Team</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="team" formControlName="team">                
                <ng-container *ngFor="let teamEl of teams">
                    <option [ngValue]="teamEl.id" [selected] = "team == teamEl.id">{{teamEl.name}}</option>
                </ng-container>
            </select>
        </div>

        ...
     
    </form>
```

I've already tried to make a conditional container to do the same thing, it even works for the gender block, but when I do the same thing for the "team" select, it's the same way as the print.

Print of how it's appearing on the screen:

[image: printscreen]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Can you share the response data in the question? Meanwhile would like to ask why cast `people.gender` and `people.team`  to array in `patchValue`. Are both gender and team using multiselect? May 1 employee consist of more than 1 `team`? It may sound correct but it doesn't make sense for `gender`.

Comment: I removed the referring arrays in formbuilder and it worked, for example before it was something like: team: [2], now I switched to: team: 2. And you helped me with that, if you want to put it as an answer I will consider it. But I'm still very curious to understand the reason for this bizarre behavior.

responsedata:
{
   "birthDate":"2021-08-18T23:23:58.3802866",
   "cpf":"78990798723",
   "email":"blabla@mail.com",
   "gender":0,
   "id":"16a6e152-2e0c-47d4-f14c-08d962b86694",
   "name":"bla bla",
   "startDate":"2021-08-18T23:23:58.380465",
   "team":2
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation for the root cause requested by Post Owner

The reason why `gender` and `team` were not working is due to this logic:

```
[selected]="team == teamEl.id"
```

When `team` is an array (for example: [2]), the comparison logic will be:

```
[selected]="[2] == 2"
```

In which both values to be compared are **different values and types**.

This logic works fine as the **requirement confirmed that `team` and `gender` are not an array**.

---

### Solution

Hence, you are **not required to cast `people.gender` and `people.team` to the array**, which would break the existing logic.

```js
this.employeeForm.patchValue({
  ...,
  gender: people.gender,
  team: people.team
});
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wjay2x)